# Phaser 3 Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite body not found

Tags: angular, phaser-framework

I am new to phaser 3

when i extended sprite

it comes out no such property

but i'm sure it has the property

although the terminal shows errors

the game still run in web well

here is my code

```
export class Planet2 extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    cellWidth: number;
    cellHeight: number;


    constructor(config) {
        super(config.scene, config.x, config.y, 'planet2');

        config.scene.physics.world.enable(this);
        config.scene.add.existing(this);

        this.body.allowGravity = false;

        this.cellWidth = config.scene.cameras.main.width / 100;

        this.body.moves = true;
        this.body.offset.x = this.cellWidth * 2;
        this.body.setSize(this.cellWidth * 8, this.cellWidth * 8, 0, 0);
        this.body.isCircle = true;


    }


}
```

[image]

and github here
https://github.com/lalalalaluk/ion-phaser-test.git

thank you so much!

Comment: You need to add Phaser  typescript definitions files. Download and add types folder from Phaser source https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser?files=1 or try to update Phaser package to latest version 3.20.0

Comment: i try update phaser to 3.20.0 it doesn't not work

Answer (score 1):

You are extending the wrong class to use for a sprite with physics enabled, which is why you are getting a type error on the body property. try `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite` for Arcade physics `Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite` for Matter physics.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, just came across the same issue, i need wrap into a class and type it to get it to work. for me im using Arcade physics.

```
class Planet2 extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    body: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body;

    constructor(scene, x = 0, y = 0, key = '') {
        super(scene, x, y, key);

        scene.physics.world.enableBody(this);
        this.body.setAllowGravity(false);
        scene.add.existing(this);
    }
}
```